# ResultSet problems in DAO

Tags: java, dao, resultset

*Forgive my lack of creativity when it comes to titeling this problem correctly.*

Hi, i've spent the last 3 hours trying to figure out this problem, and I think i've figured it out, but the solution to it still eludes me. I have this very simple code.

```
    Statement stmt = db.getStatement();
    ResultSet queryResult = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM users");

    while(queryResult.next()) {
        username = queryResult.getString("username");
        password = queryResult.getString("password");
        privilege = queryResult.getInt("privilege");

        queryResult = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM division");
        while(queryResult.next()) {}

        users.add(new User(username, password, privilege));
    }
```

Now, this piece of code is dumbed down to illustrate what the problem is in my code. I don't have a while loop which contains nothing, obviously.

I've come to realize that whenever I want to fetch something from the database, I can only do it with the resultset within one loop. If I write a "nested-resultset-loop", I either get "Operation... ResultSet closed", "Cannot find column 'username'", or some other error.

I have alot of these nested resultset loops throughout my DAO code, to fetch everything from the database. Since i'm not that strong at MySQL, this was the simple solution (I have **VERY** little time left to do this program)... Since I used to do similiar back in PHP.

I'm not saying this code is good design, but for the sake of time, I **really** do not care much at the moment about good class design. So any solution you have in mind, regardless of poor design choice is welcomed.

Another solution would be to split everything up in single loops, because that tends to work (very simple). But that means modifying alot of the code, and i'd prefer this to be the backup plan.

Comment: You ... override the resultset you are using in the outer loop, with the one that you created for the inner loop. This is ***so*** bad.

Comment: If you knew you wouldn't have done it. And ... I'm not your bro, sorry this is a professional forum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't interleave the resultsets like that, see the [API documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html):

> By default, only one ResultSet object per Statement object can be open
>   at the same time. Therefore, if the reading of one ResultSet object is
>   interleaved with the reading of another, each must have been generated
>   by different Statement objects. All execution methods in the Statement
>   interface implicitly close a statment's current ResultSet object if an
>   open one exists.

I think you'll be ok if you create separate statements for the different queries. The usual practice that I've seen is to have a separate DAO method for each query, in order to keep the DAO methods as simple and as reusable as possible. (That implies that the DAO isn't in charge of transaction demarcation, but that a higher level component, like a service, controls what's in a transaction.)

Comment: Many thanks. I tried to do seperate statements for each ResultSet like you told me, but it failed everytime with an "Operation error... ResultSet closed" error. So I found out that the problem was in the premade toolkit from my teacher, which returned the same statement object everytime getStatement() was called.

Comment: @Volatile: that's something I've seen in workplaces too: open source libraries get all the bugs shaken out of them, but reusable libraries built in-house can have all kinds of pitfalls.

Answer (score 0):

To fix your problem - do not assign the value of nested loops to the same ResultSet